# Did some reviews fall through the cracks?

Tags: bug, review, 10k-tools, top-bar

I know well why the review-counter sometimes does not show a number that matches the sum of the review tasks I could do.

Yet, lately, I noted that the review counter (for 10k+ users) is persistently around 60 or higher. It changes, and if I enter the reviews there is sometimes something to review, but it is nowhere close to  the number it displays.

At first I did not pay much attention to it as I thought maybe I had just skipped a lot. But since this persists since some time and a [similar observation was made by others](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20028/incorrect-number-of-items-in-review-queue), I wanted to bring it up.

Did something unusual happen  and might there even be something broken, or is this just a quite strange coincidence for me and a few others?

A direct way to decide this with some confidence would be if somebody with 10k+ that usually *does not review*  (or at least did not review the last days), could just visit the review-page and report if for them the numbers are roughly matching.

**Added:** Following the answer, it seems that indeed  the review counter in the top-bar does not match *at all* the actual number of review tasks lately.

I stress this is not some small fluctuation but about a difference of around <del>60</del> 130 that seems persistent since quite some time (many hours), while the counter does change (it might be too high be a fixed amount but it is hard to tell for sure).

Comment: A wild guess for the reason would be that something funny happens to reviews of suspended accounts.

Comment: If you're thinking about the recent wave of suspensions, I doubt it: the problem has been around longer than that (I'd say at least a week).

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that but it might very well be nonsense.

Comment: TBH I have no idea. I'm almost certain the bug started around the same time (March 14th according to my vote history) I started casting a lot of first close votes each day. (I remember the very high number in the orange box, but in retrospective it was probably the bug). If I had to make a guess, I'd say it's either related to the recent changes in the expiration of close votes, or the ability of the OPs to insta-close their questions as duplicates. That second one (that change is from the 9th) would kinda make sense...

Comment: It seems to me the phenomenon is not (yet) noticeable on MO, which made me focus on something specific to this site. OTOH dupe-closures are a lot less frequent on MO. So in case it is the special form of dupe-closure it could well just never have happened there. // On MESE we had one instance though, without effect AFAICT. Interesting.

Comment: [Here's an explanation](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3207593#3207593), but no solution yet.

Comment: @Woodface thanks! This also explains why it is not present on MO (no audits there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to have been corrected more or less. It shows 30 reviews now, and through private browsing window it adds up to 25 reviews.

I don't know if it's because I did a few reviews, or if something else happened. Probably the latter.

Comment: About the same here. Thanks for signaling it.

Comment: I think they are just preparing for the new Game of Thrones season.

Comment: (As should we all. Winter is coming.)